# flutter: check if user logged in

Tags: flutter

i've implemented android application using flutter , and i have created a login/signup form , it works perfect when connected with API but the problem is after i logged in and go back to any other page again when i click on the login button it shows me again the login form , what i want is to add function that detects if user logged in or not , is there a way to do it?
ps:  i tried sharedPrefrences below but it doesn't work

```html
main() async {
  // if your flutter > 1.7.8 :  ensure flutter activated
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn')??false;

  await translator.init(
    localeDefault: LocalizationDefaultType.device,
    languagesList:   <String>['en', 'ar'],
    assetsDirectory: 'assets/langs/',
    apiKeyGoogle: '<Key>', // NOT YET TESTED
  );

  // WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    LocalizedApp(
      child: Notification(isLoggedIn:isLoggedIn),
    ),
  );
}


class Notification extends StatefulWidget {
    final bool isLoggedIn;
  Notification({this.isLoggedIn});

  @override
  _NotificationState createState() => _NotificationState();
}

class _NotificationState extends State<Notification> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
   Products_FitnessAndGym()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Cart()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Wishe()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Orders(),
        )
      ],
      
      child: MaterialApp(
        
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: 
           widget.isLoggedIn ? MyHomePage(): LogIn(),
          localizationsDelegates:
              translator.delegates, /
```

and this my main.dart:

```html
main() async {
  // if your flutter > 1.7.8 :  ensure flutter activated
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await translator.init(
    localeDefault: LocalizationDefaultType.device,
    languagesList: <String>['en', 'ar'],
    assetsDirectory: 'assets/langs/',
    apiKeyGoogle: '<Key>', // NOT YET TESTED
  );
//   Future<void> main() async {
//   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
//   final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
//   var isLoggedIn = (prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') == null)
//       ? false
//       : prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');
//   // runApp(MaterialApp(
//   //   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
//   //   home: isLoggedIn ? Home() : LogIn(),
//   // ));
// }

  runApp(
    LocalizedApp(
      child: Notification(),
    ),
  );
}


class Notification extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        
   
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Products_FitnessAndGym()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Cart()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Wishe()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Orders(),
        )
      ],
      
      child: MaterialApp(
        
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: 
           isLoggedIn ? MyHomePage(): LogIn(),
          localizationsDelegates:
              translator.delegates, // Android + iOS Delegates
          locale: translator.locale, // Active locale
          supportedLocales: translator.locals(),
          .........
          ........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:
`Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => User(), ),);`
instead of
`Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => User(), ),);`

This will replace your `login` screen with `User` screen

**Edit**

```
main() async {
  // if your flutter > 1.7.8 :  ensure flutter activated
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn')??false;
   
  ...

  runApp(
    LocalizedApp(
      child: Notification(isLoggedIn:isLoggedIn),
    ),
  );
}


class Notification extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isLoggedIn;
  Notification({this.isLoggedIn});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        
   
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Products_FitnessAndGym()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Cart()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Wishe()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Orders(),
        )
      ],
      
      child: MaterialApp(
        
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: 
           isLoggedIn ? MyHomePage(): LogIn(),
          localizationsDelegates:
              translator.delegates, // Android + iOS Delegates
          locale: translator.locale, // Active locale
          supportedLocales: translator.locals(),
          .........
          ........
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224512/discussion-on-answer-by-ikerfah-flutter-check-if-user-logged-in).